# "Bien entendu" vs "bien sûr" ?

Tags: expressions

These both seem to mean approximately "of course." What is the difference in connotation and usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference in meaning and connotation but opposite trends.

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

---

Updated NGram (2019 corpus):

[image]

Nowadays, In spoken French *bien entendu* is even rarer than what the curves show for written French.